# How to apply custom classes for each element in an array after array.push() was used?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am trying to code a message UI much like a WhatsApp interface using Vue.js. Each message is an element in the array and my plan was to apply custom class to each message so that I can align the message to left or right by checking the username. The message is sent by using .push() to add a message to the original array.

My code is as follows:

```
        <div class="conversation" v-chat-scroll="{always: false, smooth: true}">

        <div v-for="message in conversationResources" :key="message.id" :class="{
            'my-message': conversationResources[conversationResources.length - 1].name == 'my name',
            'your-message': conversationResources[conversationResources.length - 1].name !== 'my name'
        }">

            <span class="message-info">{{ message.name }}: </span>
            <span>{{ message.content }}</span>
            <span class="timestamp">{{ message.timestamp }}</span>

        </div>
    </div>
```

And the corresponding CSS for each class to make them align left or right:

```
.my-message {
    text-align: right;
    background-color: blue;
}

.your-message {
    text-align: left;
```

Sending message:

```
sendMessage: function(inputMessage) {
            // Send message
            this.conversationResources.push({
                name: 'my name',
                content: inputMessage, 
                timestamp: moment.utc().format('LTS')
            })
            this.inputMessage = ''
```

The result is, every time I click send (triggering the push()), all of the previous messages' classes got renewed to the 'my-message' class and align to the wrong side. Therefore, I need the previous messages' classes to remain to same when I trigger push(). Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone commented so quickly! I tried Prisoner Raju and skirtle answer and it worked great for both! Silly me and I will make sure I will not include the whole array when I apply classes again. Cheers everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      inputMessage: '',
      
      conversationResources: [
        { name: 'my name', content: 'Hello', timestamp: 1 },
        { name: 'your name', content: 'Hi', timestamp: 2 },
        { name: 'your name', content: 'How are you?', timestamp: 3 }
      ]
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    getMessageClass (message) {
      return message.name === 'my name' ? 'my-message' : 'your-message'
    },
  
    sendMessage (inputMessage) {
      // Send message
      this.conversationResources.push({
        name: 'my name',
        content: inputMessage, 
        timestamp: 4
      })
      
      this.inputMessage = ''
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.my-message {
    text-align: right;
    background-color: blue;
}

.your-message {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="message in conversationResources"
      :class="getMessageClass(message)"
    >
      <span class="message-info">{{ message.name }}: </span>
      <span>{{ message.content }}</span>
      <span class="timestamp">{{ message.timestamp }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input v-model="inputMessage"><button @click="sendMessage(inputMessage)">Send</button>
</div>
```

I've moved the `class` to a method to make it a bit more readable.

The key change is to check `message.name` rather than `conversationResources[conversationResources.length - 1].name`.

That could be done using an object for the `class`:

```js
getMessageClass (message) {
  return {
    'my-message': message.name === 'my name',
    'your-message': message.name !== 'my name'
  }
}
```

However, given the `class` is either one or the other I've used a ternary instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<div v-for="message in conversationResources" :key="message.id" :class="{
                                                                      'my-message': message.name == 'my name',
                                                                      'your-message': message.name !== 'my name'
                                                                      }">

<span class="message-info">{{ message.name }}: </span>
<span>{{ message.content }}</span>
<span class="timestamp">{{ message.timestamp }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are renewed because of this -1 :
'my-message': conversationResources[conversationResources.length - 1]

Your chat should have align all text in left and give only class to one user.
So align all to left,

Create if class (example : get which user are logged in your tab, equal it to user are posted message - if this user are === logged one, add class to align right.
Only one class if is needed here :)

This will work for sure :)